# How to expand a particular color blob with 4 pixels?

Tags: opencv, contour

I am trying to expand the top cloth segmentation with 4 pixels. How I can achieve this with Opencv? [image]

Below is the greyscale version of the image.

[image]

Comment: You have shared a picture of your image, with axes, borders and colours added. Please share your actual, presumably greyscale, image without axes and borders so people can process it properly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have added the grey scale image.

Comment: That's better, thank you. Now what part do you mean by *"top cloth"* please?

Comment: I mean the blue region segmentation. In the grey scale image its value is '4'. So I want to expand the contour 4 pixels. Means the top cloth segmentation will have more 4 pixels expanded around it.

Comment: Ok, have a read about morphology and specifically *"dilation"* https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: I see. But when I use dilate it affects the other pixels. I have tried with kerner np.ones((3,3))*4 as my target pixel value is 4.

Comment: One approach might be to make a copy of your image containing only those pixels with value 4. Dilate the copy. Merge the dilated result back to your original (copy an entire image solidly filled with 4s, with a mask set to the dilated area, probably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


winname = 'clothes'
erode_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
dilate_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11, 11))
# dilate_kernel size = (<desired expansion> + (<erode_kernel size> - 1) / 2) * 2 + 1


def on_mouse(event, x, y, flag, img):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        # get only pixels of selected color with black background
        color = img[y][x]
        selection = np.where(img == color, img, 0)

        # split image and selection by channels as next code doesn't work
        #   with multichannel images
        channels_img = cv2.split(img)
        channels_sel = cv2.split(selection)
        for i in range(len(channels_sel)):
            # remove noise pixels of the same color
            channels_sel[i] = cv2.erode(channels_sel[i], erode_kernel)

            # now expand selected blob
            # note that dilation kernel must compensate erosion so 
            #   add erosion kernel size to it
            channels_sel[i] = cv2.dilate(channels_sel[i], dilate_kernel)

            # replace fragment on original image with expanded blob
            mask = cv2.threshold(channels_sel[i], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
            channels_img[i] = cv2.bitwise_and(channels_img[i], mask)
            channels_img[i] = cv2.bitwise_or(channels_img[i], channels_sel[i])

        # merge processed channels back
        img = cv2.merge(channels_img)
        selection = cv2.merge(channels_sel)
        cv2.imshow(winname, img)
        cv2.imshow('selection', selection)


img = cv2.imread('images/clothes.png')
cv2.imshow(winname, img)
cv2.setMouseCallback(winname, on_mouse, img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: face segment]
[image: t-shirt segment]
[image: skirt segment]

Comment: Your answer could be considerably improved by adding a description of what you are doing and also some comments... Why are you eroding? Why are you thresholding? Why are you using different sized kernels?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, erosion is to remove noise pixels of the same color after applying `np.where`, dilation kernel size is larger because it need to compensate erosion, thresholding is to make mask which is used for paste dilated segment back to image.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

- Load image as greyscale
- Extract pixels==4
- Smooth out noise with median filter
- Morphologically dilate extracted area with disk-shaped structuring element
- Create output image by putting `4` where the dilated pixels are and the original image elsewhere
- Save

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('clothes.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Extract top cloth, i.e. just class 4
topCloth = np.where(im==4,255,0).astype(np.uint8)

# Remove outlying noise pixels
topClothSmooth = cv2.medianBlur(topCloth,5)

# Create disk-shaped structuring element and dilate
SE = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(7,7))
dilated = cv2.dilate(topClothSmooth,SE)

# Apply dilated class back to original image, so where dilated > 0, put 4, elsewhere put original
res = np.where(dilated>0, 4, im)

# Save
cv2.imwrite('result.png', res)
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Here's an animated version alternating between the original and result:

[image]